# tagsinput returns wrong value

Tags: javascript, json

I have this jSon:

```
[
    { "value": "13", "text" : "fdg" },
    { "value" : "12", "text" : "fdg" },
    { "value" : "11", "text" : "fdg" },
    { "value" : "10", "text" : "dsf" },
    { "value" : "9", "text" : "testing" },
    { "value" : "8", "text" : "test" },
    { "value" : "7", "text" : "fdg" }
]
```

And the input field is:

```
<input type="text" name="productos" id="productos" class="form-control" />
```

And my js code is:

```
var cities = new Bloodhound({
    datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('text'),
    queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
    prefetch: 'url_to_json'
});
cities.initialize();

elt = $('#productos');
elt.tagsinput({
    itemValue: 'value',
    itemText: 'text',
    typeaheadjs: {
        name: 'productos',
        displayKey: 'text',
        source: cities.ttAdapter(),
    }
});
```

But when is select, for example, the text "testing", instead of returning me the value 9 (when i get the input val() ) it returns me the value 5. The same happens to me when select another items. I can't find the problem in my code. What is this returning?

I think it's important to remark that if I change the value of itemValue for another (also in jSon data) it doesn't work. I had to keep value name as itemValue.

Thanks,
Virginia

Comment: So what is the library you are using that has the bug?

Comment: It´s Bootstrap Tagsinput https://github.com/bootstrap-tagsinput/bootstrap-tagsinput. Thanks!